# tweepy stream to sqlite database - invalid synatx

Tags: python, twitter, sqlite, tweepy

The code below is streaming the twitter public timeline for a variable which output any tweets to the console. I'd like the save the same variables (status.text, status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.source) into an sqlite database. I'm getting an syntax error when my script sees a tweet and nothing is written to the sqlite database.

the error:

```
$ python stream-v5.py @lunchboxhq
Filtering the public timeline for "@lunchboxhq"RT @LunchboxHQ: test 2   LunchboxHQ  2012-02-29 18:03:42 Echofon
Encountered Exception: near "?": syntax error
```

the code:

```
import sys
import tweepy
import webbrowser
import sqlite3 as lite

# Query terms

Q = sys.argv[1:]

sqlite3file='/var/www/twitter.lbox.com/html/stream5_log.sqlite'

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

con = lite.connect(sqlite3file)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TWEETS(txt text, author text, created int, source text)")

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)

            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                                            status.author.screen_name, 
                                                            status.created_at, 
                                                            status.source))

        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % (' '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)

streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=Q)
```

Comment: Can you provide the syntax error in your question so we can have a bit more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the last line of the following code (lines 34–37 from what you posted):

```
            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                                        status.author.screen_name, 
                                                        status.created_at, 
                                                        status.source)
```

Just add a parenthesis to close the method call immediately after your tuple parameter.

Comment: No problem. Helps to have a second pair of eyes to catch typos. You may want to consider using syntax highlighting in a reasonably contrasting colour scheme so your editor can help you avoid or find these errors.

Comment: I'm still getting an syntax error when my script sees a tweet and nothing is written to the sqlite database.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()   

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TWEETS(txt text, author text, created int, source text)")
```

then later:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source))
```

Comment: It's throwing an error. I think I did it right.

'  File "stream-v5.py", line 39
    except Exception, e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'
http://pastebin.com/mLqwUa16

Comment: I'm still getting an syntax error when my script sees a tweet and nothing is written to the sqlite database.

Comment: Sorry, it has too few parameters in the sql call, try: cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source))

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: still new to this stuff. However, I got your code working by changing it to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TWEETS VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (status.text, status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.source))
con.commit()
```

It seems to me that you're reading in one status at a time. The executemany method would be for when you have more than one status. For example:

`(['sometext', 'bob','2013-02-01','Twitter for Android'], ['someothertext', 'helga', '2013-01-31', 'MacSomething'])`

I'm definitely not a wizard and am not sure what sort of impact the commit() has on every entry... I'm guessing the performance is terrible, but it works for a single term in the query.

Thanks for posting your code, I finally learned how to do streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to tweepy . But these are the modifications that worked for me . You need to add VALUES after INSERT INTO TWEETS . Also , don't forget to commit the changes . This is the link I referred to : [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470308/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-syntax-error?lq=1)

```
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO TWEETS VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                                        status.author.screen_name, 
                                                        status.created_at, 
                                                        status.source))

     con.commit()
```