# tweepy stream to sqlite database - syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, syntax-error, tweepy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tweepy stream to sqlite database - invalid synatx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434205/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-invalid-synatx)

I'm getting a syntax error in my code and I can't figure out what's causing it. This is the error the console is returning and nothing is being inputed to the sqlite file.

```
Filtering the public timeline for "@lunchboxhq"
RT @LunchboxHQ: @lunchboxhq test1   LunchboxHQ  2012-02-27 17:26:14 Echofon
Encountered Exception: near "?": syntax error
@LunchboxHQ test 1  LunchboxHQ  2012-02-27 17:26:36 Echofon
Encountered Exception: near "?": syntax error
@LunchboxHQ test 2  LunchboxHQ  2012-02-27 17:26:51 Echofon
Encountered Exception: near "?": syntax error
```

my sqlite file only has:

```
... tableTWEETSTWEETSCREATE TABLE TWEETS(txt text, author text, created int, source text)
```

Can you guys help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks. The code is below.

```
import sys
import tweepy
import webbrowser
import sqlite3 as lite

# Query terms

Q = sys.argv[1:]

sqlite3file='/var/www/twitter.lbox.com/html/stream5_log.sqlite'

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

con = lite.connect(sqlite3file)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TWEETS(txt text, author text, created int, source text)")

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)

            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                                            status.author.screen_name, 
                                                            status.created_at, 
                                                            status.source))

        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % (' '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)

streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=Q)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `executemany` you have three "?"-marks but 4 parameters. It is probably missing an additional questionmark. Also you should probably just use [execute](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) instead of `executemany` since you only do one insert. Like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                               status.author.screen_name, 
                                               status.created_at, 
                                               status.source))
```

Also the correct SQL according to [this](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) would be:

```
INSERT INTO TWEETS VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Still having the same problem even after adding the additional ?. It's also not writing the correct information to the sqlite file.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer I just added a note about using `execute` maybe that helps.

Comment: it didn't work. thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer Found one more possible cause, check my answer.