# How to transfer streaming info from stdout to a mySQLdb in python?

Tags: python, database, twitter, tweepy

I have a file that pulls info from twitter in python and runs the status messages into my shell. I want to take them from the shell and into a database. I do not know how to do that. I do not have a database made for it either, I will go on the database stack to question that. My code is as follows:

```py
import time
import MySQLdb
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Go to http://dev.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=" # Omitted "
consumer_secret=" # Omitted "

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=" # Omitted"
access_token_secret=" #Omitted "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# If the authentication was successful, you should
# see the name of the account print out
print api.me().name

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
        """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
        This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
        """
        def on_data(self, data):
            print data
            return True

        def on_error(self, status):
            print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
        l = StdOutListener()

        stream = Stream(auth, l)    
        stream.filter(track=['search term'])
```

How do I get the info from the stream into a database? I also want to filter the stream to only allow certain information in. The only information I want to go into the database is the following:

1. Message Author
2. Message
3. Date / Time Stamp
4. GEO if available
5. Source ie Tweetdeck, web, mobile yaddda yadda
6. Was the message RT'd

Comment: Thats a whole lotta information you want someone to provide :-/

Comment: ohhhhhh :-( maybe I can break the problem down into small problems, I'll have to draw it out, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question asks for a lot of information, so I am just going to give you an overview of what you need...

First off, there are examples of this exact approach both on SO and across internet. Here is a paste example from [this tutorial](http://andrewbrobinson.com/2011/07/15/using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-stream/)

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', 
                                    subsequent_indent='    ')
    conn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'dbUser','dbPass','dbBase')

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (text, date) VALUES (%s, NOW())' ,(status.text))
            print self.status_wrapper.fill(status.text)
            print '\n %s  %s  via %s\n' % (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.source)
        except Exception, e:
            # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
            # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
            pass
```

This example uses a different database driver. But you would use the `on_status` handler to receive new data, and split it up into values. Then you create an sql INSERT to put it into your database.

Here is an sqlite3 example from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470308/tweepy-stream-to-sqlite-database-syntax-error):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TWEETS(?, ?, ?, ?)", (status.text, 
                                               status.author.screen_name, 
                                               status.created_at, 
                                               status.source))
```

Both of these example require that you use your database client to connect, and then get a cursor (which is an object that makes your queries and lets you look through the results). You can [check out a tutorial on MySQLdb](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlpythontutorial/) for a pretty good overview of how to set everything up and make queries.

If you end up having a more focused problem, then that can be addressed separately.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do what you said and come back when I have a much narrower problem to work with. I apologize for the massive question.

Comment: No prob! The more specific of a question, the more specific the answer can be!

Comment: thanks @jdi I'm sure I'll be back many times over, I appreciate the help and awesome screen name